# Error: Missing name after . operator in qz.print(config, data).catch(function(e) { console.error(e); });

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I am googling for the last couple of days and cannot find a relevant solution anywhere on the net.

I want to print to POS printer Zjiang 58 connected through usb to dsktop from google spreadsheet via code in google script editor using qz tray installed on my win7 32-bit desktop but get out an error:

Missing name after . operator. (line 53, file "Code") Dismiss :(

The script which I want to make to work is:

```js
function POSprint() {

var rsvp = require('/Software/QZ Tray/demo/js/dependencies/rsvp-3.1.0.min.js');
var Sha256 = require('/Software/QZ Tray/demo/js/dependencies/sha-256.min.js');
var qz = require('/Software/QZ Tray/demo/js/qz-tray.js');

var config = qz.configs.create("POS-58");

var data = [
   { type: 'raw', format: 'image', flavor: 'file', data: 'assets/img/image_sample_bw.png', options: { language: "escp", dotDensity: 'double' } },
   '\x1B' + '\x40',          // init
   '\x1B' + '\x61' + '\x31', // center align
   'Beverly Hills, CA  90210' + '\x0A',
   '\x0A',                   // line break
   'www.qz.io' + '\x0A',     // text and line break
   '\x0A',                   // line break
   '\x0A',                   // line break
   'May 18, 2016 10:30 AM' + '\x0A',
   '\x0A',                   // line break
   '\x0A',                   // line break    
   '\x0A',
   'Transaction # 123456 Register: 3' + '\x0A',
   '\x0A',
   '\x0A',
   '\x0A',
   '\x1B' + '\x61' + '\x30', // left align
   'Baklava (Qty 4)       9.00' + '\x1B' + '\x74' + '\x13' + '\xAA', //print special char symbol after numeric
   '\x0A',
   'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' + '\x0A',       
   '\x1B' + '\x45' + '\x0D', // bold on
   'Here\'s some bold text!',
   '\x1B' + '\x45' + '\x0A', // bold off
   '\x0A' + '\x0A',
   '\x1B' + '\x61' + '\x32', // right align
   '\x1B' + '\x21' + '\x30', // em mode on
   'DRINK ME',
   '\x1B' + '\x21' + '\x0A' + '\x1B' + '\x45' + '\x0A', // em mode off
   '\x0A' + '\x0A',
   '\x1B' + '\x61' + '\x30', // left align
   '------------------------------------------' + '\x0A',
   '\x1B' + '\x4D' + '\x31', // small text
   'EAT ME' + '\x0A',
   '\x1B' + '\x4D' + '\x30', // normal text
   '------------------------------------------' + '\x0A',
   'normal text',
   '\x1B' + '\x61' + '\x30', // left align
   '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A',
   '\x1B' + '\x69',          // cut paper
   '\x10' + '\x14' + '\x01' + '\x00' + '\x05',  // Generate Pulse to kick-out cash drawer**
                                                // **for legacy drawer cable CD-005A.  Research before using.
];

   qz.print(config, data).catch(function(e) { console.error(e); });
  
}
```

Any idea how to make it work is very much wellcomed.

Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

I have just received an answer from the qz tray support person:

Tres Finocchiaro and he said:

Error: Missing name after . operator.

This is due to Google Apps Script not supporting ES6 Promises.  Polyfill does not appear to work either.  You can find the exact error this occurs on by pasting the contents of qz-tray.js into the editor.  The error is thrown here:

_qz.security.callCert().then(sendCert).catch(sendCert);

The reason is, this is the first unchecked call to ".then", which is an RSVP/A+/Promise.   No matter of hacking seems to get this to work.  But I wouldn't waste time on that just yet... read on.

Second reason this won't work... There's no support for WebSockets inside Google Apps Scripts.  This is a core component of communication between browser and the printing API.

Some people claim to use Google's form of AJAX instead (i.e. UrlFetchApp.fetch(...)) but this isn't the same as a websocket and even if it were, there's no concept as "localhost" which is where the websocket is running.

Third reason this won't work.... We support connection on two URLs: "localhost" and "localhost.qz.io".  Both work with HTTPS.  When attempting to fetch using Google Apps Script, this is what happens:

DNS error: https://localhost:8181
Bad request: https://localhost.qz.io:8181

I've read posts suggesting there's ways to run Google Apps Script on the "server" (wherever that is) but then the issue of connecting to "localhost" becomes even worse as Google's servers aren't going to run our software, and even if they did, the printers wouldn't be accessible.

As of right now, I don't see an easy way to solve your problem.  If you're looking for a quick hack to print raw content from Google Sheets, you could probably hack together a URL that does it. This would require knowledge of Java and you'd have to fork the source code.

For example, you can easily open a link from Sheets pointing to =HYPERLINK("http://localhost:8182","http://localhost:8182")  You could manipulate the URL to send a payload to the application containing a chunk of base64 data such as a  printer name and some raw data, but this would all have to be written from scratch by a Java developer.

The code would reside inside doGet() function.

This is not something we'd add to the base product, but you could fire up an instance in IntelliJ and hack at it.  Our compilation tutorial is about as simple as a software project can get. https://github.com/qzind/tray/wiki/Compiling

Best regards,

Nevertheless, all comments and opinions and your experiences how you solved printing from google sheet to thermal pos printer are still most wellcomed because I am still looking for a solution to provide me this facility.

Thanx.